# I rotate screen manually to Landscape but the taskbar buttons dont use the new full width of 480, rather they only use the 320 portion of the bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I rotate my screen to landscape mode

```
- (void)rotateScreen
{ 
    [self.tabBarController.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    self.tabBarController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.tabBarController.view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
    self.tabBarController.view.center  = CGPointMake (240.0, 160.0);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
```

}

It all seems to work well,

The view and Navbar are rotated, the postion of the Tabbar changes position to the bottom of the screen.

The problem is that the buttons on the Tabbar do not use the full width of the screen rather they only use the space of 320pixles rather than growing onto the full width of the bar, which has become 480 pixels now.

Is there someway I can ask it to grow in width?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issues when the views you have added are added as subviews using the addSubView method instead of being pushed to the navigation bar.

That is the first thing I would review.

Comment: Hi Khurram, and you believe this causes problems with the space the TABBAR buttons use when rotated? Because the view itself is perfect, the problem is that the buttons on the tabbar only use 320pixles of width while the tabbar is 480 pixels in width.

Comment: Yes, because the rotation event is not passed to subviews. Furthermore, all views inside the tabbar will not receive the events either. I do not know your view hierarchy. For my case, I had to push the Tabbar controller to the navigation controller and my rotations started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you anchor the tab bar to the right edge of the view? The anchors play an important role in sizing you view based on the parent.
Read about UIViewAutoResizingMask in developer documentation for more info.

Comment: You recommend I do anchor it? I just added it with code and didnt specify any anchoring.. its the defaults.